# The script only works once in UPBGE

Tags: scripting, game-engine

the solution (if it helps someone)
just remove space in ray2 (thanks musikai in blenderartists)

if ray():
own["key"] = " "
cont.owner.state = 1

to

if ray():
own["key"] = ""
cont.owner.state = 1

in state 1 I have 2 always connected to python controller
the first of the python controller has a script that moves the character

the next always has a script that when detects the ground and the space key changes to state 2
In state 2 I have a delay that activates the jump, then always that is connected to a python controller to move in a different way in the air and finally an always connected to a python controller to detect the ground and return to state 1

[image]

The problem is that when I’m in state 1 and I jump, that is I press space key (change to state 2) then I go back to 1 and when I want to jump again, it changes to state 2 (that is good) but the code that moves the characther in a different way is not executed

[image]

that is the jump and movement only works once

here a post where you can download my test/game
https://blenderartists.org/t/script-works-only-once/1513308

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. Could you edit your post and translate all text to English? If you are not comfortable writing it yourself, feel free to use any automated online translation service.

Comment: thaks you Duarte Farrajota Ramos and try to do what you say, pardon me if my english not is good

Comment: Although there are 'upbge' and 'game-engine' tags for this Q&A site, I think most people here will be using the native version of Blender which no longer includes the game engine rather than the UPBGE version which is maintained separately so it's unlikely that you'll get an answer here. You might have more luck asking on one of the other [UPBGE community web forums](https://upbge.org/#/community).

Comment: thanks you @JohnEason Anyway I have seen similar posts with answers